# Can I cast function pointer void* to std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

the function pointer `void*` is loaded by `dlsym()`, can I cast it to `std::function` ?

suppose the function declaration in lib is
`int func(int);`

```
using FuncType = std::function<int(int)>;
FuncType f = dlsym(libHandle, "func"); // can this work?
FuncType f = reinterpret_cast<FuncType>(dlsym(libHandle, "func")); // how about this?
```

Comment: Pro-tip: if someone casts something to a `void*`, the *only thing* you can cast it to is what it originally was (outside of things like `char*` and the like).

Comment: You mustn't use `reinterpret_cast` with non-"standard layout" class types at all.

Comment: Yes, you can run with scissors. But please don't. ;-) Slightly more helpful comment: The C++ standard does not guarantee that you can roundtrip-cast safely from a function pointer like `int (*)(int)` to a data pointer like `void *`. This is because on some (now rather obscure) platforms, a data pointer and a code pointer do not have the same size. However, on a POSIX platform, this is hopefully not the case(?), because how else would you use `dlsym` to get a function pointer? You can add a `static_assert(sizeof(void *) >= sizeof(int(*)(int), "Data pointer too short")` just in case.

Answer (score 15):

No, the function type `int(int)` and the class type `std::function<int(int)>` are two different types.  Whenever you use `dlsym`, you must cast the resulting pointer only to a pointer to the actual type of the symbol.  But after that, you can do with it what you want.

In particular, you can construct or assign a `std::function` from a pointer to function:

```
using RawFuncType = int(int);
std::function<int(int)> f{
    reinterpret_cast<RawFuncType*>(dlsym(libHandle, "func")) };
```

Answer (score 2):

Write something like this:

```
template<class T>
T* dlsym_ptr(void* handle, char const* name) {
  return static_cast<T*>( dlsym( handle, name ) );
}
```

then:

```
FuncType f = dlsym_ptr<int(int)>(libHandle, "func");
```

works, and it isolates the cast into a helper function.

Note that when casting from `void*` to another pointer type, use `static_cast`.  Only use `reinterpret_cast` when nothing else works, and `static_cast` explicitly lets you convert from `void*` to any other pointer type.